# Selenium Changing language of Internet Explorer Driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to change the language setting of my IE Driver in Selenium. Each TestFixture runs in a different language. Please note that i have added all required languages as part of Internet Explorer settings and i just need to change it programmatically. Is it possible? If yes, how can i change it?

I read that IE Settings need to be altered via Registry. Is there any way to select the language from the languages already available as part of the list in IE?

Comment: Try changing `os_locale` using the `os` module of your programming language before you launch the test.